# MLengine 'module' object has no attribute 'estimator'

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-composer

Running [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/machine_learning/deepdive/08_image/flowers_fromscratch.ipynb) on ML engine using Cloud composer but am receiving the following error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'estimator'

Even though I am importing `import tensorflow as tf` and it exits on the following line:

```
  estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn = image_classifier,
```

Runtime version is 1.8 similar to the version using the repo.

```
t3 = MLEngineTrainingOperator(
    task_id='ml_engine_training_op',
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    job_id=job_id,
    package_uris=["gs://us-central1-ml/trainer-0.1.tar.gz"],
    training_python_module=MODULE_NAME,
    training_args=training_args,
    region=REGION,
    scale_tier='BASIC_GPU',
    runtimeVersion = '1.8',
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: Can you give the CMLE job_id (email to: cloudml-feedback@google.com) associated with this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `setup.py`, make sure you put tensorflow in it as
`REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['tensorflow==1.8.0']`. or some other version. Then don't forget to re-generate tar and upload.

Also, in my case, `MLEngineTrainingOperator` doesn't seem to pick `runtime_version` or `python_version` at all into ML Engine.